# What is a grandfathered syntax, as in the MATLAB "radon" function?

Tags: deprecated, matlab, undocumented-behavior

I found a function with a "secret" input, which someone can perhaps explain? What could be the reason? Are there many cases of such a thing?

In the documented syntax of `radon` function, there are two ways to call the function - the conventional one with inputs of `I` and `THETA`, (for image and desired projection angles), and also an option to omit `THETA`, and give only `I` as input.

But in the comments inside the `radon.m` file, there is another part at the end, that is described as "grandfathered syntax". This allows *three* inputs, including also the number of desired projections. And, it really works!

So, why isn't this documented? Has it been available in the past, and then deleted/changed (as "grandfathered syntax" would suggest)? So why does this still work?

And, another question about `radon.m`:

The main part of the function is computed by calling another function, called `radonc`. What is it? Where does it reside? I can't find it, or any mention of it anywhere.

Comment: My guess is that they removed it from the documentation to "strongly encourage" people to use the new syntax. It still works for backwards compatibility -- so that code written in older MATLAB versions still works in newer MATLAB versions. This process is very common; it's called [depracation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation). This is the MathWorks' take on it.

Comment: As for your second question (again, guessing here) -- whenever some function name ends in "c", it usually indicates that it has been implemented in C and then compiled to a MEX file, usuallty to speed up  the execution of some portion of the function.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks. About the MEX file- how can my machine run the file, if it doesn't have the file itself? Or i just didn't find it...?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Grandfathered" syntax typically means that it's a syntax that

1. used to be documented and supported
2. still needs to be kind of supported because some customers still rely on it, and MathWorks wouldn't want their code to break
3. is no longer recommended, and is therefore undocumented so that new users will not start to rely on it
4. may get completely removed in future.

`radonc` is in `\toolbox\images\images\private`. The `which` command won't find it because it's in that private directory, and so can only be called by functions in the directory immediately above (which includes `radon` itself). The file is `radonc.mexw64` (possibly a different mex file extension if you're on a different platform to me), indicating that it's implemented as compiled C code rather than MATLAB code (and in case this is why you're asking, it means you can't see the source).

Edit: Note that in the same directory there is also a file `radonc.m`. This file doesn't do anything, as the mex file has higher precedence; it is there to provide help for the `radonc` function. If you type `help radonc`, you'll see that it shows the help text provided by the comments of `radonc.m`.

Comment: I've tried all of this, but in my version (R2008a) it says: "radonc not found". Anyway, thanks for the explained answer :)

Comment: As explained, if you try to execute `radonc`, or if you type `which radonc`, MATLAB will not find it. This is because it's in a private directory, and therefore not on the path - it can only be called from functions in the directory immediately above, which includes the `radon` function. Nevertheless, it is there. (Note, I don't have 8a available, but I believe everything I've said is true for that version).

Comment: I also believe all your explanations are true. What I wrote was only as regards to the "help radonc", and what my matlab answered me...

Comment: Try which -all radonc. MATLAB will find it if you have Image processing toolbox installed :)